# JSONLint Validation error--expected EOF

Tags: json, couchdb

I'm attempting to format some JSON to import into CouchDB. A single string seems to work, but I want to import a fairly large set (about 700 rows) and JSONLint is giving me the error

```
Parse error on line 8:
...   "comments": " "}{    "disc_number":
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']'
```

Here's the JSON.  Perhaps I'm just being stupid, but I'm not seeing the issue.

```
{
"disc_number": "SC2267",
"track_number": "1",
"disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
"song_title": "It's All About the Pentiums",
"artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
"comments": " "
}{
"disc_number": "SC2267",
"track_number": "2",
"disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
"song_title": "Dare To Be Stupid",
"artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
"comments": " "
}{
"disc_number": "SC2267",
"track_number": "3",
"disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
"song_title": "One More Minute",
"artist": "Weird Al Yankovic""comments": " ",

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to pass multiple disconnected objects in a single JSON, but JSON only supports a single "main" object per file. JSONLint is throwing that error at line 8 because it expects the file to be done at the end of the object, but instead it continues with another one.

This first part by itself is a valid JSON:

```
{
  "disc_number": "SC2267",
  "track_number": "1",
  "disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
  "song_title": "It's All About the Pentiums",
  "artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
  "comments": " "
}
```

This is not:

```
{
  "disc_number": "SC2267",
  "track_number": "1",
  "disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
  "song_title": "It's All About the Pentiums",
  "artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
  "comments": " "
} { "hello": "world!" }
```

An alternative solution would be:

```
{
  "trackX": {
    "disc_number": "SC2267",
    "track_number": "1",
    "disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
    "song_title": "It's All About the Pentiums",
    "artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
    "comments": " "
    },
  "trackY": { "etc": "etc" },
  "trackZ": { "etcetera": "misc" }
}
```

Or:

```
{
  "tracks": [{ "trackA": "trackAData" }, { "trackB": "trackBData" }]
}
```

[json.org](http://json.org/) has a brief but complete description of how to write a valid JSON file. It's a quick read; it should help you find a good way to format your data.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your JSON is a collection of JSONs. You will have to manually add an object wrapper around you objects and separate them by "," to make your file parseable.

```
{
"tracks": [{
    "disc_number": "SC2267",
    "track_number": "1",
    "disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
    "song_title": "It's All About the Pentiums",
    "artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
    "comments": " "
}, {
    "disc_number": "SC2267",
    "track_number": "2",
    "disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
    "song_title": "Dare To Be Stupid",
    "artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
    "comments": " "
}, {
    "disc_number": "SC2267",
    "track_number": "3",
    "disc_title": "Hits of \"Weird Al Yankovic\" - Vol. 2",
    "song_title": "One More Minute",
    "artist": "Weird Al Yankovic",
    "comments": " "

}]}
```